# IBM process server v8.5.5 - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BO Service is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-process-server

I was trying to get the HelloServiceApp example working under the IBM Process Server v8.5.5 (Windows 7 - 64-bit).

Every time I "Add remove" the service, the server restarted and show me the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.bo.BOCore (initialization failure) (...) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BO Service is not supported or disabled in this profile."

I'm using the IBM Integration Designer 8.5, IBM process server v8.5.5, on windows 7 64-bit.

Thx!

This error shows in several blogs but no one had a solution.

**Log IID**

```
The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start. View the Details to display the exceptions and server logs that occurred during the publish.  

======== HelloServiceApp ========

Failed to add or remove the application from the server: HelloServiceApp
[2/4/15 15:10:51:215 GMT] 0000009d InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of HelloServiceApp started.
[2/4/15 15:10:54:045 GMT] 0000009d FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\IID\PS\v8.5\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_e8a23fca_15.02.04_15.10.54.0455087446130989773166.txt com.ibm.ws.bpm.cmdfrmwrk.task.WBICleanupTask 200
[2/4/15 15:10:54:045 GMT] 0000009d FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\IID\PS\v8.5\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_e8a23fca_15.02.04_15.10.54.0457409362458603361484.txt com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.delegator.DelegatingTaskProvider 70
[2/4/15 15:10:54:215 GMT] 0000009d FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\IID\PS\v8.5\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_e8a23fca_15.02.04_15.10.54.075739919462372947986.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run 328
[2/4/15 15:10:54:235 GMT] 0000009d InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application HelloServiceApp failed.
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:259)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bo.BORALCacheCleaner.clearScope(BORALCacheCleaner.java:38)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.al.util.BOCacheHelper.clearBOCache(BOCacheHelper.java:51)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.al.scope.ScopeContextManager.removeContext(ScopeContextManager.java:896)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.al.scope.ScopeContextManager.clearSubContext(ScopeContextManager.java:533)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.al.ALFactory.remove(ALFactory.java:243)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bpm.cmdfrmwrk.task.WBICleanupTask.performTask(WBICleanupTask.java:73)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.delegator.DelegatingTaskProvider.delegatePerformTask(DelegatingTaskProvider.java:458)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.delegator.DelegatingTaskProvider.performTask(DelegatingTaskProvider.java:424)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.BPMTaskProvider.performTask(BPMTaskProvider.java:100)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:796)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BO Service is not supported or disabled in this profile.
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bo.BOCore.init(BOCore.java:107)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.bo.BOCore.<clinit>(BOCore.java:70)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:237)
[2/4/15 15:10:54:225 GMT] 0000009d SystemErr     R  ... 11 more
```

**IBM Process Server v8.5.5 at localhost**

```
[2/3/15 10:42:39:351 GMT]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError SourceId:com.ibm.ws.bpm.cmdfrmwrk.task.WBICleanupTask ProbeId:200
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.bo.BOCore (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:177)
    at com.ibm.ws.bo.BORALCacheCleaner.clearScope(BORALCacheCleaner.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.al.util.BOCacheHelper.clearBOCache(BOCacheHelper.java:51)
    at com.ibm.ws.al.scope.ScopeContextManager.removeContext(ScopeContextManager.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.al.scope.ScopeContextManager.clearSubContext(ScopeContextManager.java:533)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.al.ALFactory.remove(ALFactory.java:243)
    at com.ibm.ws.bpm.cmdfrmwrk.task.WBICleanupTask.performTask(WBICleanupTask.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.delegator.DelegatingTaskProvider.delegatePerformTask(DelegatingTaskProvider.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.delegator.DelegatingTaskProvider.performTask(DelegatingTaskProvider.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.bpm.deploy.BPMTaskProvider.performTask(BPMTaskProvider.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:796)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BO Service is not supported or disabled in this profile.
    at com.ibm.ws.bo.BOCore.init(BOCore.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.bo.BOCore.<clinit>(BOCore.java:70)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:237)
    ... 11 more

Reporter:null
```

Comment: What's the code you're using? Try running something different. If you get the same error, it's not a programming problem, and you're likely to get more help on another StackExchange -- Server Fault might be a good place to look at.

Comment: Yes, I tried all the 5 examples that came with the solution

Comment: Then it's not the code that's the problem, it's your setup. You'll want a different site.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the profile management tool whether you have a proper IBM process server advanced profile created??

If you are not having the advanced profile created, it means you are trying to deploy the apps on a server (can be WAS or IBM BPNM) which dosen't possess BPEL/mediation execution capabilities

If you have the advanced profile ,It can be that your WPS profile creation encountered some error and didn't complete properly. You can try creating a new IBM BPM advanced profile using PMT and deploy the app there.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the profile for the local *BPM Process Server* is not configured correctly. You can check the `<BPM install root>/properties/profileRegistry.xml` to see if the profile is augmented with the valid templates.

It the profile only has the template of `..profileTemplates\default`, the local Process Server is not configured correctly.